# Showing $ \tan\frac{A+B}{2}= \frac{\sin A+\sin B}{\cos A+\cos B}$

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification

**Problem Statement**

When helping a high school student, I came across this problem: show that

$$
\tan\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)=
\frac{
\sin\left(A\right)+\sin\left(B\right)
}{
\cos\left(A\right)+\cos\left(B\right)
}
$$

**My Solution 1**

Define $X=\frac{A+B}{2}$ and $Y=\frac{A-B}{2}$. We have

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sin\left(A\right)&=\sin\left(X+Y\right)\\
&=\sin\left(X\right)\cos\left(Y\right)+\sin\left(Y\right)\cos\left(X\right)
\\
\\
\sin\left(B\right)&=\sin\left(X-Y\right)\\
&=\sin\left(X\right)\cos\left(Y\right)-\sin\left(Y\right)\cos\left(X\right)
\\
\\
\cos\left(A\right)&=\cos\left(X+Y\right)\\
&=\cos\left(X\right)\cos\left(Y\right)-\sin\left(X\right)\sin\left(X\right)
\\
\\
\cos\left(B\right)&=\cos\left(X-Y\right)\\
&=\cos\left(X\right)\cos\left(Y\right)+\sin\left(X\right)\sin\left(X\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Substitute these to the RHS then we have

$$
\frac{
\sin\left(A\right)+\sin\left(B\right)
}{
\cos\left(A\right)+\cos\left(B\right)
}
=
\frac{\sin\left(X\right)}{\cos\left(X\right)}=\tan\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)
$$

**My Solution 2**

Define $O$ as origin of the cartesian plane. Consider two unit vectors

$$
\begin{aligned}
\overrightarrow{OP}&=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\left(A\right)&\sin\left(A\right)\end{bmatrix}^{\top}
\\
\overrightarrow{OQ}&=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\left(B\right)&\sin\left(B\right)\end{bmatrix}^{\top}
\end{aligned}
$$

The two vectors form angles $A$ and $B$ respectively with the positive $x$ axis. The following vector bisects the angle $\angle POQ$:

$$
\overrightarrow{OP}+\overrightarrow{OQ}
=
\begin{bmatrix}\cos\left(A\right)+\cos\left(B\right)&\sin\left(A\right)+\sin\left(B\right)\end{bmatrix}^{\top}
$$

Therefore, we have

$$
\tan\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)=
\frac{
\sin\left(A\right)+\sin\left(B\right)
}{
\cos\left(A\right)+\cos\left(B\right)
}
$$

**My Solution 3** (new)

Using a unit circle, the following picture illustrate the proof:

[image: Picture Proof]

**Remarks**

I find the second solution simpler and wish to ask others if there are other elementary alternative solutions.

Comment: I think these are the two easiest ways, they are both very natural and I can't think of anything simpler.

Comment: @JeanAbouSamra I have just added a new alternative

Answer (score 1):

Another very easy way (by using [sum-to-product formulas](https://trigonometrywithereza.wordpress.com/sum-to-product-and-product-to-sum/)).

$\require{cancel}\dfrac{\sin A+\sin B}{\cos A+\cos B}=\!\dfrac{\color{#8888FF}{\cancel{\color{black}2}}\!\sin\left(\!\frac{A+B}2\!\right)\!\color{#8888FF}{\cancel{\color{black}{\cos\left(\!\frac{A-B}2\!\right)}}}}{\color{#8888FF}{\cancel{\color{black}2}}\!\cos\left(\!\frac{A+B}2\!\right)\!\color{#8888FF}{\cancel{\color{black}{\cos\left(\!\frac{A-B}2\!\right)}}}}\!=\!\tan\left(\!\dfrac{A\!+\!B}2\!\right).$